# How can I find where a SqlDateTimeOverflow is coming from?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, entity-framework

I have a relatively complex synchronization operation that is suddenly throwing a SqlDateTimeOverflow error bubbling up through MS Entity Framework.

Is there a way to have SQL 2005 server log failed transactions so we can find where this is coming from? Any tips on how we can 'flag' these transactions to at least find out on what table this is occurring?

**Edit:** BTW, debugging code is in progress of course, but tracing this on the SQL level would narrow this down quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trace SQL with SQL Server Profiler. This is easy as you don't have to change your app.

Most common cause of this exception is an uninitialized `DateTime` property. SQL Server's weirdly limited `DATETIME` type can't handle a date in the year 0.

Comment: Is there such a thing as 'year 0'? I thought they are numbered from 1. But `datetime` limitation is indeed somewhat weird.

Comment: @Andriy, you are probably right. Either way, it's well before the date in the 1700s that `DATETIME` starts at.